# Instrucción if con varios operadores y condiciones desde PHP

Tags: php, condiciones

Quiero que se ejecute, en `PHP`, un `insert` en `mysqli` pero sólo **si se hace clic en cualquiera de los 4 botones**. El problema es que cuando la página se carga, igual se ejecuta la instrucción dentro del `if` con el `insert`, pero yo sólo lo necesito (como ya dije anteriormente) que solamente se ejecute cuando se hace clic en algunos de esos botones y nada más.

A lo mejor estoy poniendo mal los `if`, los paréntesis, o bien, el uso y ubicación de los operadores. Ya he probado algunas otras combinaciones y sigue entrando al `insert` sin siquiera haber realizado algún clic en los botones. Como ven puse todas las condiciones en el mismo `if`, a lo mejor debo separarlo en distintos `if`. Ojala me puedan decir, qué sería más efectivo y que funcione claro. 
El código de `PHP` es:

```
if(isset($_POST['Ant']) && !empty($_POST['Ant']) || 
  (isset($_POST['Sig']) && !empty($_POST['Sig'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Pri']) && !empty($_POST['Pri'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Ult']) && !empty($_POST['Ult'])))
    {
      $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into esttips (ID,NroTips,UserIP,Fecha) 
      Values (?,?,?,?)");
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'siss',$id,$F,$ip,$fecha2);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}
    }
```

Voy a explicar un poco mejor. Debo aclarar que todo el código lo tengo en el mismo archivo (*index.php*). El evento de los clics de los botones está realizado en `JQuery` haciendo uso de `AJAX` el cual ya está funcionando:

```
$('body').on('click', '#Ant, #Sig, #Pri, #Ult', function(e) {
 ...
 ...
}
```

Sólo me falta, como ya comente al principio, que cuando se hace clic en cualquiera de los botones (`#Ant`, `#Sig`, `#Pri`, `#Ult`) me haga la inserción en la BD que tengo de MySQL. Pero se ve que al estar todo el código en el mismo archivo, al cargar la página ya me inserta los valores, cuando yo sólo quiero que lo haga solamente cuando se clickea algún bóton.

¿Se puede hacer todo en el mismo index.php o debo hacer lo de php aparte en otro archivo y luego desde el index.php realizar la llamada?

Comment: Si recargas una página que enviaste previamente con un formulario, vuelve a entrar con el payload enviado, Eso hace que tu `if` entre en acción de nuevo.

Comment: No, no se recarga la página. Hablo de la primera vez que se carga la página. Además, hago uso de AJAX para controlar los clics de los botones y sólo refrescar una parte (cuando se hace clic en los botones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, te falta un parentesis para que sean 4 bloques dentro de la condición if:

```
  if((isset($_POST['Ant']) && !empty($_POST['Ant'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Sig']) && !empty($_POST['Sig'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Pri']) && !empty($_POST['Pri'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Ult']) && !empty($_POST['Ult'])))
```

Comment: No me doy cuenta en donde faltaría ese paréntesis que dices. Además en mi IDE no me marca error de cierre o falta de algún paréntesis.

Comment: No es que falte un solo paréntesis, sino una pareja de ellos "( )"  en el primer bloque, te los especifico con comillas: if("("isset($_POST['Ant']) && !empty($_POST['Ant']")") || 
  (isset($_POST['Sig']) && !empty($_POST['Sig'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Pri']) && !empty($_POST['Pri'])) || 
  (isset($_POST['Ult']) && !empty($_POST['Ult'])))

Comment: Has tenido toda la razón, era un problema de paréntesis. Ya lo he cambiado como me has dicho y me ha funcionado. Ahora solamente entra cuando haces clic en cualquiera de esos botones especificados ;)